# Regex matching for counting CSS selectors

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting (and failing) to specify a single regex which I can use with PHP's `preg_match_all()` for the following:

```
.foo { bar }
.baz, .bot { bip, bop }
```

I need to count all `{` and only `,` which are not between {}. Given the sample above, I should have exactly three matches. My difficulty (ignorance) is that I do not understand how to specify the "do not match commas between curly braces" part. My current regex matches all commas and opening curly braces:

```
({)*(,)*
```

Comment: The 3 matches should be .foo, .bar and .bot, right? Not bar, bip and bop?

Comment: @sp00m - the text is unimportant. I am trying to count the total number of CSS selectors, which can be determined (one way) as "the total number of opening braces" plus "the total number of commas which are not enclosed by curly braces". There are certainly several other approaches which would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\{.+?\}|,
```

Meaning:

```
\{   # If you can match a brace
.+?  # then also grab the minimum amount of other charactors
\}   # until you reach the closing brace
|,   # or if there was no brace then just match a comma
```

Comment: Great! Just needed to ignore line breaks: `preg_match_all('/\{.+?\}|,/s',$contents,$matched);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a close but not exact count this is a quick and dirty way to do so

```
$selector_count = substr_count($css, ',') + substr_count($css, '{') - substr_count($css, '@media');
```

It will count any `,` in the css, so rules like `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` that use `,` will be counted as well. This can be useful if you know about the limitations. The accepted solution doesn't work with `@media`.